# How to Do a For Loop Instead of a While Loop in Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to implement for loops instead of while loops but have no idea how too. This is a while loop script I created. How would I make this into a for loop instead of a while loop? I'm not really understanding how for loops work.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

read -p "Number of Papers To Grade:
" numpap

av=$numpap
while [ $av -gt 0 ];
do
  av=$(($av - 1))
  echo "Enter a Number (1-100): "
read num
if [[ $num -ge 1 && $num -le 100 ]] ; then
     echo ""
   else
     echo "Enter a Number Between 1-100
     "
     av=$(($av + 1))
     total=$(($total - num))
   fi
total=$(($total + num))
done
averag=$(($total/$numpap))
echo Average Grade = $averag%
echo "Done"

Comment: `for ((av=numpap; av>0; --av)); do ... done`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
var=5
for ((value=var; value>0; --value))
do
    echo $value
done
```

This gives the output :

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

You can have a look at more ways to write loops using while / for / until : [here](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-loops.php)

Answer (score 1):

I modified your script to run using a `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Number of Papers To Grade:" numpap

for ((av=numpap; av>0; av--))
do
  echo "Enter a Number (1-100): "
read num
if [[ $num -ge 1 && $num -le 100 ]] ; then
     echo ""
   else
     echo "Enter a Number Between 1-100"
     av=$(($av + 1))
     total=$(($total - num))
   fi
total=$(($total + num))
done
averag=$(($total/$numpap))
echo Average Grade = $averag%
echo "Done"
```